# Tensorflow RNN sequence training

Tags: tensorflow

I'm making my first steps learning TF and have some trouble training RNNs.

My toy problem goes like this: a two layers LSTM + dense layer network is fed with raw audio data and should test whether a certain frequency is present in the sound.

so the network should 1 to 1 map float(audio data sequence) to float(pre-chosen frequency volume)

I've got this to work on Keras and seen a similar TFLearn solution but would like to implement this on bare Tensorflow in a relatively efficient way.

what i've done:

```
lstm = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(LSTM_SIZE,state_is_tuple=True,forget_bias=1.0)
lstm = rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(lstm)
stacked_lstm = rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([lstm] * 2,state_is_tuple=True)
outputs, states = rnn.dynamic_rnn(stacked_lstm, in, dtype=tf.float32)
outputs = tf.transpose(outputs, [1, 0, 2])
last = tf.gather(outputs, int(outputs.get_shape()[0]) - 1)
network= tf.matmul(last, W) + b

# cost function, optimizer etc...
```

during training I fed this with (BATCH_SIZE, SEQUENCE_LEN,1) batches and it seems like the loss converged correctly but I can't figure out how to predict with the trained network.

My (awful lot of) questions:
how do i make this network return a sequence right from Tensorflow without going back to python for each sample(feed a sequence and predict a sequence of the same size)?

If I do want to predict one sample at a time and iterate in python what is the correct way to do it?

During testing is dynamic_rnn needed or it's just used for unrolling for BPTT during training? why is dynamic_rnn returning all the back propagation steps Tensors? these are the outputs of each layer of the unrolled network right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some research:

> how do i make this network return a sequence right from Tensorflow
>   without going back to python for each sample(feed a sequence and
>   predict a sequence of the same size)?

you can use state_saving_rnn

```
class Saver():
def __init__(self):
    self.d = {}
def state(self, name):
    if not name in self.d:
        return tf.zeros([1,LSTM_SIZE],tf.float32)
    return self.d[name]
def save_state(self, name, val):
    self.d[name] = val
    return tf.identity('save_state_name') #<-important for control_dependencies

outputs, states = rnn.state_saving_rnn(stacked_lstm, inx, Saver(),
                                       ('lstmstate', 'lstmstate2', 'lstmstate3', 'lstmstate4'),sequence_length=[EVAL_SEQ_LEN])
#4 states are for two layers of lstm each has hidden and CEC variables to restore
network = [tf.matmul(outputs[-1], W) for i in xrange(EVAL_SEQ_LEN)]
```

one problem is that state_saving_rnn is using rnn() and not dynamic_rnn() therefore unroll at compile time EVAL_SEQ_LEN steps you might want to re-implement state_saving_rnn with dynamic_rnn if you want to input long sequences

> If I do want to predict one sample at a time and iterate in python what is the correct way to do it?

you can use dynamic_rnn and supply initial_state. this is probably just as efficient as state_saving_rnn. look at state_saving_rnn implementations for reference

> During testing is dynamic_rnn needed or it's just used for unrolling for BPTT during training? why is dynamic_rnn returning all the back propagation steps Tensors? these are the outputs of each layer of the unrolled network right?

dynamic_rnn does do unrolling at runtime similarly to compile time rnn(). I guess it returns all the steps for you to branch the graph in some other places - after less time steps. in a network that use [one time step input * current state -> one output, new state] like the one described above it's not needed in testing but could be used for training truncated time back propagation